# what license does rhev use?

Tags: redhat

rhev is the virtualization production from redhat,It's not free for use.
I find the trail ISO,but I did'nt find the source code.

1. So what's the license of the rhev use?
2. Does it open source?

Answer (score 0):

The upstream version at ovirt.org is completely opensource